# Cannot get map to display on meteor app using google map api3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, meteor

Hi I am new to meteor and I am working on my first application beyond the tutorial. I am coming from a node + express world. I am currently trying to transform an application I built on Node+express using the google maps java script api v3 into a meteor application so that I may be able to distribute it to specific devices. In my trials I got the app working locally on the web by placing my map code into the head element of my html page and it ran as intended. Once I tried to import it onto an android device I received the error :

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

from that error it led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383866/google-maps-with-meteor-not-working) telling me to move my map code into a Template.rendered function because the meteor script is being run before the google maps api is being loaded which seemed correct. I followed the instructions on that post and I am now being served with a new error stating :

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'rendered' of undefined
```

Through googling this took me to [this blog post](http://technokayiti.blogspot.com/2014/08/meteor-creating-package-errors-how-to.html) in reference to my error. It states that there is an issue in the order I am loading my html page in. It guides you to change your packages.json file to restructure the order that your files are being served in. The issue here was my packages file is not similarly set up the way hers is and I am having trouble relating it to her file. Any advice would be appreciated I will include code below for my current application.

Html:

```
    <head>

    <title>Google Maps App</title>

    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE&sensor=true">

    </script>


    </head>

    <body>


       <template name="maps">

          <div id="map-canvas"></div>

       </template>
    </body>
```

js:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {

      Template.maps.rendered = function() {
        var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    }




    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.startup(function () {

      });
    }
```

packages:

```
    meteor-platform
    autopublish
    insecure
    twbs:bootstrap
    fortawesome:fontawesome
    jquery
```

Thank you for your time in advance. Please let me know if there is anything I can include that would be more helpful.

EDIT 1: Currently looking into using [this meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps) for googlemaps with javascript api v3 will post updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wich meteor version are you using?

run `meteor --version` and if is under 1.0.4 change the rendered to this([rendered = function() was depurated](https://forums.meteor.com/t/template-foo-rendered-deprecated-whats-correct/1758)), now we use [onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) .

```
Template.maps.onRendered(function(){
   //map code here
 });
```

Also you don't need the  `google.maps.event.addDomListene` here, you can do it more like this.

```
//appName/client/helpers.

initMap = function(){
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
}

//appName/client/views/map/map.js

Template.maps.onRendered(function(){
       initMap
     });
```

But the code its ok. check [this](https://github.com/Ethaan/Meteorjs-sample-map) junk [DEMO](http://ethaan-map.meteor.com)

**UPDATE**

This is how the html should look.

```
<head>
    <title>Google Maps App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDG1mocxosoC9cq-ucFO3vdZCcUxyKa6B4&sensor=true">
    </script>  
</head>
  <body>
    {{> maps}}
  </body>
<template name="maps">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
 </template>
```

And the Javascript.

```
  Template.maps.onRendered(function(){
     initMap();
    })
initMap = function(){
    var map;
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into it for me. My version is current 1.1.0.2. I am going to look into your demo and work on applying my map into it. I will keep you updated. Shouldn't take too long.

Comment: Template rendered should work instead,put a console.log inside the function initialize to be sure that the functions get initied

Comment: The console.log() is not being hit. Its not allowing it to be rendered. I am still getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'rendered' of undefined" 

and it is pointing to line 3 which is

        Template.maps.rendered = function() {

Comment: try with this html  `<body>{{> maps}}</body>` put the template outside the body tag also like the answer says you **can't** use `template.maps.rendered` you should change to `template.maps.onRendered()` it never gonna works.

Comment: Hey thank you for sticking with me. When I change it to onRendered() I am getting left handed assignment error. If I use just onRendered the errors go away. Only issue is the initialize function is still not being ran. My console.log is not firing. I believe this may be due to the fact that there is no #map-canvas div to load map into possibly now. Here is my [github](https://github.com/zzrot/map2) with the code where it currently is at containing the changes you suggested - the onRendered() and + onRendered without the ().

Comment: I believe I implemented your changes correctly. There are now reflected in [my github](https://github.com/zzrot/map2). It runs and there are no errors. A map is still not being displayed on either the web browser or when I am trying to launch it on android device emulator though it is just a blank page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75752/discussion-between-zzrot-and-ethaan).