# google is not defined, adding autocomplete to google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I have the following error, when trying to add the autocomplete function to my google map: `google is not defined`. I am using the Meteor package `dburles:google-maps` for the implementation.

***Here is my code***

**.html**

```
<template name="search">
  {{> map}}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="search">
      <form>
        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <input id="search" type="text">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**.js**

```
// Loading map on startup
Meteor.startup(function() {
  GoogleMaps.load({ key: 'API-KEY', libraries: 'places' });

  var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById(search), {
    types: ['(cities)']
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autoComplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.geometry) {
       map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
       map.setZoom(15);
    }
  });

});

Template.map.helpers({
  locationsOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290),
        zoom: 12
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
  GoogleMaps.ready('locations', function(map) {
    // Add a marker to the map once it's ready
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.options.center,
      map: map.instance
    });
  });
});
```

Any ideas where the error might be coming from?

Comment: I haven't used this package, but my guess is that `GoogleMaps.load({ key: 'API-KEY', libraries: 'places' });` runs asynchronously. You have to wait for `GoogleMaps.load({ key: 'API-KEY', libraries: 'places' });` to finish running before you have access to the `google` object when you are trying to define `var autoComplete`. Try putting code that depends on the `google` object inside `GoogleMaps.loaded()`

Comment: See if [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753048/cannot-get-map-to-display-on-meteor-app-using-google-map-api3) helps.

Comment: There is always a mention of div with an `id="map-canvas"`, but the package loads the map only through `{{> googleMap name="locations" options=locationsOptions}}`, and when I inspect the page there is not `id` in the html structure